# Confused where to place php file (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel

I Have to Implement text message feature for my application for that i have a php file which i get from service provider where need to place db details.and give its path to service provider to add in server. I am confused where to place and according to him if i give that file path in url it should return contact number and message body but i am unable to test it.

**script looks as**

```
    <?php
    //  MySQL table outbox:
    // CREATE TABLE outbox(sender VARCHAR(255), rcpt VARCHAR(255), body VARCHAR(255));
    $mysql_host = "localhost";


    $mysql_base = "school_laravel";

    $mysql_user = "root";

    $mysql_password = "";

    $table = "outbox";

    mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
    mysql_select_db($mysql_base);

    mysql_query("LOCK TABLES $table WRITE, $table AS $table" . "_read READ");

 $get_query = "SELECT * FROM $table AS $table" . "_read";
 $del_query = "DELETE FROM " . $table;
 if ($_GET['device'] != '') {
  $suffix = " WHERE sender='" . $_GET['device'] . "'";
     $get_query .= suffix;
  $del_query .= suffix;
 }
 $result = mysql_query($get_query);
    echo '<messages>';
    while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<message msisdn="' . $array['rcpt'] . '">' . $array['body'] . "</message>\n";
 }
 mysql_query($del_query);
 mysql_query("UNLOCK tables");
    echo '</messages>';
?>
```

My Question is that where should i place it in laravel Directory and is it possible to get a table details as i mentioned DB details in above script.

Thanks for Help

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: please anyone can give it as answer using PDO or something else

Comment: @AlexHowansky where should i place this php file?

Answer (score 4):

Even if it saves you a minute, I would not use that code on your site. It would be difficult to use on a Laravel site unless you rewrite it. If you are going to have to rewrite it anyway, maybe you could do it in a Laravel way.

The script you have looks fairly straight forward to rewrite. This code is untested. I would not expect to copy and paste it into your app and have it work without modifications, but here are the basic steps.

Step 1 - [Create a Model for your table.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models)

**app/Outbox.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Outbox extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'outbox';

}
```

Step 2 - [Create a controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#basic-controllers)

**app/Http/Controllers/MessagesController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Outbox;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MessagesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function show($sender)
    {

        $messages = Outbox::where('sender', $sender)
                      ->firstOrFail();

        $ids_to_delete = $messages->pluck('id');

        Outbox::destroy($ids_to_delete);

        return view('messages')
                 ->with('messages', $messages);;
    }
}
```

Step 3 - [Create a view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views)

**resources/views/messages.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>
          laravel.com
      </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <messages>
        @foreach($messages as $message)
          <message msisdn="{{ $message->rcpt }}">{{ $message->body }}</message>
        @endforeach
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Step 4 - [Add a route for your new controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing)

**app/routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('messages/{sender}', 'MessagesController@show');
```

Step 5 - Visit the new URL

`http://localhost/messages/device`

Where **device** is whatever `$_GET['device']` would have been.